# Is download speed in linux greater than in windows, even in a vm? really?

Tags: windows, linux, download, bandwidth

Weird! Any explanation? Is it due to some QoS related bandwidth reservation?

[image]

Comment: Have you done repeated tests? Can you tells more about the systems in question and your network?

Comment: @slhck Well, had done it several times but with same result. As for the systems, the host is windows & the vm runs linux.

Comment: the ping and upload speeds are the same - I suspect speedtest download ran into a download cache burst.. like @slhck said need more details - network adapter, type of connection, how many systems sharing the network and so on